# VPN connection is locked in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: vpn

After editing and adding a new connection (with ivacy-configuration file), when I try to use the connection a lock-symbol is shown near the connection icon and connection fails.

[image: screen-shot]

cunfiguration file is like this:

dev tun
proto tcp
remote germany-tcp.ivacy.net 80
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-auth Wdc.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
route-method exe
route-delay 2
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
float
auth-user-pass
auth-retry interact
ifconfig-nowarn

syslog has more info, how to show (part of) logfile?
however, a few lines here:

```
   Jun 20 15:25:11 sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK gcr-prompter[3031]:
   GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. **This is discouraged**. Jun
   20 15:25:29 sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK NetworkManager[801]: <info>
   [1497943529.8551]
   vpn-connection[0x557ee04c9150,677a6c1a-298a-434f-b873-f4936fd4c820,"Russia-Moscow-TCP",0]:
   VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3) Jun 20 15:25:29
   sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK NetworkManager[801]: <info> 
   [1497943529.8551]
   vpn-connection[0x557ee04c9150,677a6c1a-298a-434f-b873-f4936fd4c820,"Russia-Moscow-TCP",0]:
   VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received Jun 20 15:25:29
   sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK nm-openvpn[3040]: **WARNING**: file
   '/home/sebu/Downloads/OpenVPN-Configs/Wdc.key' is group or others
   accessible Jun 20 15:25:29 sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK
   nm-openvpn[3040]: OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)]
   [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on May 10 2017
   Jun 20 15:25:29 sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK nm-openvpn[3040]:
   library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08 Jun 20
   15:25:30 sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK nm-openvpn[3040]: WARNING: No
   server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See
   http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info. Jun 20 15:25:30
   sebu-Lenovo-ideapad-110-15ISK nm-openvpn[3040]: NOTE: the current
   --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
```

Comment: Check https://support.ivacy.com/. Your config file is incorrect.

Comment: yes Zanna i did so, they suggested to try out different servers and different protocols. In Win10 i had to use the Windows driver ... haha just used for connect to this web (from China)

Comment: icacy support can't help since they use Vers 14, however Win10 is able to establish a connection with only 3 parameter: **server,username,password.**  Where can i get help for my problem with Ubuntu 17.04, @heynnema ?

Comment: I can't promise anything, but if you can show us your config file, with the username/password deleted out, and any log file that shows us connection process/errors would be helpful. ivacy support gave you a very lame answer.. they should be able to provide support no matter what version OS.

Comment: @heynnema: I tried to create a tutorial for myself and for ivacy support in order to let them know what exactli i did. see here: [link](http://www.g2p.ch/myRGi/programme/frontend/docs/ivacy_OpenVCN.php). The provited parameterfile 'Germany-Frankfurt-TCP.ovpn' looks like this: 

client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote germany-tcp.ivacy.net 80
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
tls-auth Wdc.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 1
mute 20
route-method exe
route-delay 2
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
float
auth-user-pass
auth-retry interact
ifconfig-nowarn

i will search for logfiles and add

Comment: Where are the ca.crt and Wdc.key files? Have you manually entered them into the Network Manager configuration via the GUI? fyi: the lock icon on the network icon indicates that VPN thinks it's up.

Comment: @heynnema: sorry i forgot to mention: lock Icon is flashing, not stable. ca.crt and Wdc.key files are in same directory  as .ovpn files .

Comment: I think ca.crt and Wdc.key files  were handled by the 'create saved connection' process.  --->  WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.   what does it mean?

Comment: It used to verify that germany-tcp.ivacy.net is who they say they are. To get vpn entries out of syslog, use `grep -i vpn /var/log/syslog*`.

Answer (score -1):

**solution**
[image]

change configuration file to **United States-Chicago-UDP.ovpn**,delete 
United States-Chicago-TCP and add United States-Chicago-UDP instead.
 
Unfortunetly the number of available Servers is redused, i miss server in Switzerland and need to go to Win10 and connect to ch1.dns2use.com with a default configuration. (Windows almost become a Linux-baby now)
note: Ivacy Win10-setup fails without meaningful information, so i had to use default Windows configuration.
However, we look hopefully into the future ...

Thanks to @heynnema for great support!